# Send Email to Multiple Addresses Android

Tags: android, email-address

I want to select a number of email addresses and then send an email to all of them.

My code is as below:

```
emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{listofemailaddresses});
emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");
emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Constants.SMS_MESSAGE);
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));`
```

`listofemailaddresses` is a string which contains all the emails separated by a ',' sign. But the To field is always empty in this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to your code:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { "appsupport@YOUR_DOMAIN.com" });
```

This will fill the "To" section of your screen.

Answer (score 6):

If you having the list of email addresses seprated by `,` then split that string to get individual email id as follow:
`String [] emailList = emailAddresses.split(",");`

now use *emailList* with your `Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL` key,as this will show all email addresses  inside *to* field of send email form.

How about this code:

```
final Intent emailLauncher = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailLauncher.setType("message/rfc822");
emailLauncher.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailList);
emailLauncher.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "check this subject line");
emailLauncher.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hey check this message body!");
try{
       startActivity(emailLauncher);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = null;
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "abc@gmail.com" , "test@gmail.com", "xyz@test.com"});
startActivity(intent);
```