# How to send email to multiple recepients in android?

Tags: android, email

I'm a newbie in android. Please help me. I'm not able to send email to multiple recipients.
Here is my code.

```
public class SendEmailActivity extends Activity{

EditText subject_ed,message_ed;
TextView subject_tv,message_tv;
Button send_btn;

 ArrayList<String> emailList;
 ArrayList<Integer> idList;
 int eventId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts_email_sms_layout);
    setupViews();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    eventId =  b.getInt("EventId");//event id
    idList = b.getIntegerArrayList("IdList");//list of Ids
    emailList = b.getStringArrayList("EmailList");//list of email ids
    buttonListeners();
}

public void setupViews()
{
    subject_ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_subject_email);
    message_ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_msg_body);
    subject_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_subject_email);
    message_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_msg_body);
    send_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_send_sms_email);
}               

public void buttonListeners()
{
    send_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // String to = textTo.getText().toString();
              String subject = subject_ed.getText().toString();
              String message = message_ed.getText().toString();
            Object[] to =  emailList.toArray();
//            for(int i = 0; i<=emailList.size(); i++)
////                  {
////                      
//                  String  to=   emailList.get(0);
////                     
////                  }



              Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              for(int i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
                {
                    Log.i("String is", (String)to[i]);
                    //String[] str = (String[])to[i];
                     email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,",'" +(String)to[i] + "'");
                }

              email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
              email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

              //need this to prompts email client only
              email.setType("message/rfc822");

              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
             // finish();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Does the app crash? Any errors?

Comment: check this link of stack overflow may be this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716924/send-email-to-multiple-addresses-android

Comment: @Shreya S : No errors.. It doesnt sent email at all.. Just bring up the email. but I cant sent email at all

Comment: @Abhinav Singh Maurya: Thanks for the link but I tried this. not working for multiple recepients!!

Comment: Can't u pass more than one string in that string array?

Comment: @Shreya: I'm able to get the email ids in the LogCat. But the same thing is not appearing in the 'to' field.

Comment: you are putting to much extras for to field may be problem is due to that. try to add array directly and then check if its working or not

Comment: @ Abhinav Singh Maurya: I'm able to click the sent button and it will go to the email client in the device. But subject and message part will be filled up as my edittext values but the to field is not filled up.. and if i give email ids manually and press send button, the sending process shows as sending and closes down but the email is not sent at all

Comment: @Abhinav Singh Maurya:its not working still

Comment: Conversion wrong from List to string[] that is 
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] arrayOfStrings = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]); actually you need to do like this.

Comment: @Harish : Thanks a lot my half problem is solved now.. The addresses are appearing in the to field of the email client but emails are not sent even though it shows sending message..

Comment: Once try by changing intentname.setType("text/plain");

Comment: @Harish : Still doesnt work :(

Comment: can you please keep the startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail...")); this in try block and catch the error so that we know getting any exception.

Comment: @Harish : I'm not getting any exception

Comment: have you written anything in your catch block like toast or log message..

Comment: yup log.. but nothing is showing in the logcat

Comment: Before Intent can you add android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND
android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL
android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT
android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT you can do like this try...:)

Comment: @ Harish : I'll try this too.. :(

Comment: have you solved your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First your conversion from List to String[] is wrong you need to do as follows..

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] arrayOfStrings = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

And next thing is you need to mention android.Content.Intent as follows..

So finally you need to change as follows

```
ArrayList<String> emailList;
emailList = b.getStringArrayList("EmailList");
String[] emailArray;

Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

for(int i = 0; i < to.length; i++){
    Log.i("String is", (String)to[i]);
    email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
                   emailList.toArray(new String[emailList.size()]));
}
email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);    
email.setType("message/rfc822"); //or email.setType("text/plain");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, String value)
```

When setting email recipients, instead there is another method which accepts a string array which must be used for emails

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, String[] value)
```

So your block

```
for(int i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
{
    Log.i("String is", (String)to[i]);
    //String[] str = (String[])to[i];
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,",'" +(String)to[i] + "'");
}
```

Would simply become

```
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
```

See the android developer reference for more details on using [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) specifically the [EXTRA_EMAIL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL) argument which expects a string array, not a single string.

Comment: Try using `public Intent putStringArrayListExtra (String name, ArrayList<String> value)` and passing in emailList as value - I just noticed that to is declared as Object[] rather than String[] due to the return value of the toArray method which may cause an issue

Comment: My half problem is solved now..Just followed What Harish suggested. The addresses are appearing in the to field of the email client but emails are not sent even though it shows sending message

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion, I thought the string array list extra method would simply be a convenience method for the same thing, glad to hear you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would put this on a different thread so that you don't have any process on the Activity thread (or UI thread). This is a good [android tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) on how to do this. Threading is really important to understand in Android. If you have time I would watch this [threading tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-P1eiRy-klk) as well.

```
button.Onclick(){
  // get all the messages information
  // the button to send the emails has been collected
  new SendEmailTask().execute(messages)
}
```

Then in your Async Task you can send all of the messages

```
SendEmailTask extends AsyncTask<Message,Void,Void>(){

  function doInBackground(Message... msgs){
    for(Message m : msgs){
     // process each of your messages
     // send the messages out
    }
  }
  function onPostExecute(){
    // tell the UI thread that you are finished
  }

}
```

Good Luck!