# How to add all the selected recipients to mailbox through Intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am New to Android.I am trying to send mail to all the selected recipients(getting from JSON), selecting the recipients through checkbox.The dialog box for sending email appears again and again for each but I want to send in one time.I am posting my code.

```
ArrayList<Getter_Setter> user_list;
btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < user_list.size(); i++) {
                //send mail with these selected emails
                if (user_list.get(i).isSelected()) {
                    String[] item = {user_list.get(i).getEmail()};

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String [item.length]);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(UserInfo.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14501062

Comment: sry.... I have tried it but it is not clear to me...

Comment: i think you are a starter to programming , better ask some experienced one who can tell the basic programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U r doing the part for sending the email in a for loop. Hence the mail dialog appears many times.

Put the code for sending mail after the loop.Like this.

```
String[] item = new String[user_list.size()];
int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < user_list.size(); i++) {
            //send mail with these selected emails
            if (user_list.get(i).isSelected()) {
                item[index] = user_list.get(i).getEmail();
                index++;
            }
        }
```

Also in the Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, u need to pass  the array with the actual email id's.

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, item);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(UserInfo.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: I am getting error so I changed it to this--> item[i] = String.valueOf(new String[]{user_list.get(i).getEmail()}); and now I am getting something like <Ljava.lang.String> @53ghdh3 ...something like this in mailbox

Comment: what error were u getting?

Comment: array initializer is not allowed here...

Comment: check the edited code.

Comment: still the same error...item[index] can't use item like this..

Comment: remove curly braces from user_list.get(i).getEmail(); . If this does not work then post ur logcat output.

Comment: Thanks....it's worked

Answer (score 0):

If `String[] item = {user_list.get(i).getEmail()};` is a String[] of email addresses then change your EXTRA_EMAIL from

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String [item.length]);
```

to

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, item);
```

Comment: putting "item" doesn't work because it shows the dialog again and again for multiple selects.