# Properly format email recipient addresses

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

I have a list of email addresses on my database that I fetched into an array. I want to be able to send messages to all of them with email `intent`. Everything worked fine but I discovered that my gmail app was bouncing the messages because most of the email addresses were not properly formatted. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IZTM.png)

How do I remove those tags such that the email addresses would be formatted to show just comma separator for the recipients?

```
private List<String> userEmails = new ArrayList<>();
    String emailsWithTags = TextUtils.join(",", userEmails);
            String result = emailsWithTags.replaceAll("<","").replaceAll(">", "");
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"+ result));
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mMessage.getText().toString());
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Notification ");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email to multiple recepients in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496687/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recepients-in-android)

Comment: this answer didn't' remove the tags for me

Comment: but it does not show those tags on my Logcat. am confused about this.

Comment: Did you solved the problem? I tested it now and it was working correctly ie without the tags

Comment: @sano, it works well when I used yahoo app, but show the tags with gmail app.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer mentioned in the comment didn't help you, You can do a simple string replace to remove the `<` `>` tags as given below,

```java
String emailsWithTags = TextUtils.join(",", userEmails);
String result = emailsWithTags.replaceAll("<","").replaceAll(">", "");
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"+ result));
```

Comment: I got the same result. tags still visible. please review my updated code